Suggestion: Remove "Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve."
This is one of our close reasons:

Questions seeking product recommendations or service reviews are off-topic because they tend to become outdated quickly. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve.

Here's an example question closed with this reason:
How do you buy bitcoin using Perfect Money?

Is there anyone who is selling or buying bitcoin through perfect money?(A Russian money payment system) Please help me out and enlighten me on this.

The question is pretty clear. He wants to take money from e-commerce provider #47 and use it to buy Bitcoins. He's described his situation and the problem he's trying to solve.
However, it's such a specific question that it will probably not be answered. If it is, it will probably never be used again before it goes out of date.
So, I think the last sentence of that close reason should be removed. It's not helpful.
Thoughts?

relate: How could our “Off-Topic close reasons” be improved? What would be another useful one?

I have proposed the following close reason a while ago:

Questions seeking service reviews are off-topic, because they tend to attract subjective, low-quality, and spam answers, while on the other hand services in the Bitcoin space are still evolving rapidly, rendering answers outdated quickly. For more information see meta-discussion.

Unfortunately, it requires the approval of another moderator to become active.
Update:
The proposed close reason has been activated.

I'm going to ask for help from the community managers to see if someone could review it for me.

Why is this close reason different from the one in the post you linked?

I don't remember my thinking exactly, but I think the one I posted here was supposed to replace it. Unfortunately, I just learned that change proposals on these close reasons don't cause automatic notifications, but rather you have to talk to people directly.

@NickODell Or maybe I don't get what you mean. Could you elaborate?

The version that you posted in the other thread still has the part that says, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve. Why the difference between the two? Is there a distinction between editing a close reason, and replacing it?

BTW, I like this close reason a lot. Is there anything I can do to help chase down a Community Manager to help solve this?

@NickODell I've already talked shortly to Shog9 and TimPost today. Unfortunately, one Moderator can only deactivate a close reason by himself, but can't create or edit one without the approval of another. I think I created this one after I edited the old one to include service reviews, because I didn't like the part about "describing your situation", but I guess I never remembered to have it approved.
